# How do I set up a single Hard drive as a node on my MAAS server?

Tags: server, maas

I just set up a MAAS server and have hard drives within the physical server that I want to configure as nodes. How do I add them  either through web interface or manually via the command line?

Comment: Did my answer clear it up for you? Do you still have questions?

Answer (score 0):

MaaS is designed as a tool for managing multiple physical machines, not multiple hard drives. (If your goal is to manage hard drives, then there are tools that do not require MaaS).

If you have a powerful enough server, you could use virtualization software like KVM or Virtualbox to create a couple of virtual machines, which you could then manage with MaaS. The only reason I can see to do this though is to test MaaS -- if you are trying to manage many (or even just a few) virtual machines, there are easier ways to do it, like Libvirt.

(I know my answer doesn't have a ton of specifics, but that is because I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, or what you end goal is).